# Virtual wireless interfaces in different modes on single radio

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, ad-hoc-network

I'm looking for a USB wireless adapter that will support virtual interfaces running in different wireless modes *at the same time*. I've found USB wireless adapters that support multiple wireless modes (managed, master, ad-hoc), and adapters that can run multiple virtual interfaces. But I haven't been able to find one that will run multiple virtual interfaces in different modes.

Basically what I want to do is to run two virtual interfaces, one in ad-hoc mode, and the other in master mode acting as an access point, using only one physical wireless adapter. I know this functionality is typical in wireless routers, but I need a USB adapter that will do the same thing in linux. Any suggestions?